# How to stop jest describe without throw all the test

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I want to stop a whole describe of JEST without throwing an error or stoping the other describes.

Im writing e2e test for my app with JEST and PUPPETEER, I write the test in a way every DESCRIBE its a flow of the path and every IT its a step, inside a IT I want to stop the flow if the pages dont match some conditions.

```js
describe('Book a Room', ()=> {
it ('enter on main page' async() => await mainPage.navigateToMainPage())
it('go to book room page', async() => await bookRoomPage.navigateToBookRoomPage())
// The function its inside the "bookRoomPage"
it('check if the user can book room', () => {
 if (!page.userCanOpenARoom()) {
// DONT EXECUTE THE NEXT IT BUT CONTINUE WITH THE OTHER DESCRIBE
  }
})
it('go to book preview...', async() => bookRoomPreviewPage.navigateToBookRoomPreviewPage());
// REMAINING FLOW
})
```

I already try with `process.exit(0)` but exit the whole process

Answer (score 0):

You can try out what this blog says [here](https://medium.com/@walreyes/sharing-specs-in-jest-82864d4d5f9e) its for sharing specs in your test suites which is pretty handy. But for your case specifically you could extract your page cases in separate suites and then dynamically `include` the test case on runtime if a condition is met.

Something like: 
Include Spec function `shared_specs/index.js`

```
const includeSpec = (sharedExampleName, args) => {
  require(`./${sharedExampleName}`)(args);
};

exports.includeSpec = includeSpec;
```

Test A `shared_specs/test_a.js`

```
describe('some_page', () => {
  it...
})
```

Test B `shared_specs/test_b.js`

```
describe('some_other_page', () => {
  it...
})
```

and then in your test case

```
// Something like this would be your path I guess
import {includeSpec} from '../shared_specs/includeSpec.js'

describe('Book a Room', async ()=> {

if (page.userCanOpenARoom()) {
  includeSpec('test_a', page);
} else {
  includeSpec('test_b', page); // Or dont do anything
}

});
```

Just make sure that you check the paths since

```
require(`./${sharedExampleName}`)(args);
```

will load it dynamically at runtime, and use `includeSpec` in your `describe` blocks not `it` blocks. You should be able to split up your test suites pretty nicely with this.

Comment: Im already importing my "its" from other files. In fact I run all the it inside that other file, I just want to avoid put a `if` if I can stop the whole test.

Comment: I would honestly just split the test cases up better so you can include what you need when condition is met. You still need to put the `if` there to stop the process so to say. So you cant really get rid of it

Comment: I try with your example and its failing because my test are async.